# How to determine which display an Android activity is using?

Tags: android

As of Android O the following code can be used to launch an activity on a display other than default one:

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
options.setLaunchDisplayId(d.getDisplayId());
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

In this case a new task is created which may start additional activities on the alternate display. From an activity how can I detect which display is currently being used? I was thinking the `Window` class would tell me but I can't find any function there.

Comment: Maybe from your activity you can call `getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)` to get a `WindowManager` and then use `getDefaultDisplay()`? Never tried but it seems plausible.

Comment: Thanks @BenP. The method is poorly named, and the docs do say: "Despite the name of this method, the display that is returned is not necessarily the primary display of the system (see DEFAULT_DISPLAY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Ben P. is correct, despite the name `WindowManager#getDefaultDisplay()` actually returns the `Display` object which happens to be associated with the instance of the `WindowManager` when it was obtained which will accurately reflect the display the activity is currently running in.

> Returns the Display upon which this WindowManager instance will create
>   new windows.
>
> Despite the name of this method, the display that is returned is not
>   necessarily the primary display of the system (see
>   Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY). The returned display could instead be a
>   secondary display that this window manager instance is managing. Think
>   of it as the display that this WindowManager instance uses by default.
>
> To create windows on a different display, you need to obtain a
>   WindowManager for that Display. (See the WindowManager class
>   documentation for more information.)

So assuming you invoked `Activity#getSystemService` to obtain the `WindowManager` you should get the correct `Display` object back. `WindowManager` and `SearchManager` seem to be [special case managers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-mr1-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#5909) that are aware of the context from which they were obtained unlike most managers.